# Select inside ng table, when reloading data in ng table the page goes back to top

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are using a ng table to render some data on a page. Inside the table a ng-repeater renders line by line values from an array of objects. One of the columns is a select box and its values are taken from an array declared and populated inside the controller.

This is the declaration of the array:

```
$scope.CharacteristicsToChange = [];
```

This is the population of the array which is somewhere in a method:

```
if ($scope.ItemProfile.ProductionDateRegistration != 'No')
    $scope.CharacteristicsToChange.push({ Name: 'Production date' });

if ($scope.ItemProfile.BestBeforeDateRegistration != 'No')
    $scope.CharacteristicsToChange.push({ Name: 'Best before date' });
```

And the select box is:

```
<select class="form-control" id="ddlCharacteristics" ng-options="characteristic.Name as characteristic.Name for characteristic in CharacteristicsToChange" name="Characteristic" ng-model="inventory.SelectedCharacteristic" required>
    <option value="" class="select-placeholder"> Select characteristic type</option>
</select>
```

Our problem is that when the data for the ng table is reloaded ( every 10 seconds ) and the page is scrolled to the bottom, the page is going back to the top.

I think that the problem is the array from where we take the values for select ( $scope.CharacteristicsToChange ), because when I deleted the population part of this array, the reloading problem had not occurred anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any instances of `ng-if` or `ng-show` on the page? Without seeing more code, it sounds like you may actually be removing / hiding elements on the DOM when you reload your data, and then re-creating it (thus making it scroll back to the top)

Comment: I have some ng-show but the expression inside of them is the constantly the same, therefore if an item is shown when the page is loaded it will be shown all the time while the page is open.

Comment: What does the code look like that populates the refreshed data every 10 seconds?